# Выборка в Excel дубликатов с временым условием

Tags: excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, формулы или способ, который можно применить в Excel или в Google sheets, чтобы решить задачу.

Имеется следующая таблица (фрагмент):

`+---------------------+-----+
| date                | sum |
+---------------------+-----+
| 15.09.2018 11:37:43 | 10  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 15.09.2018 11:36:59 | 10  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 15.09.2018 11:17:10 | 10  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 14.09.2018 04:25:42 | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 14.09.2018 04:25:42 | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 14.09.2018 04:00:32 | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+`

Необходимо выделить все строки с одинаковыми sum. При этом выбранные строки не должны разнятся в date больше, чем на 2 минуты. Ожидаемая таблица:

`+---------------------+-----+
| date                | sum |
+---------------------+-----+
| 15.09.2018 11:37:43 | 10  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 15.09.2018 11:36:59 | 10  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 14.09.2018 04:25:42 | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+
| 14.09.2018 04:25:42 | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В столбец 'С' формула:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--($B$2:$B$7=B2);--($A$2:$A$7>=A2-2/1440);--($A$2:$A$7<=A2+2/1440))>1
```

Фильтр в столбце `С` по значению `ИСТИНА`. Копировать отфильтрованные строки, вставить на другой лист или ниже таблицы с исходными данными.

Для выделения данных на месте эту же формулу применить в условном форматировании.